# Регулярное выражение для разделения по запятым, кроме экранированных

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

**Дано:** Строка, например, вида такого: "`Казнить|, нельзя, помиловать.`".
**Задача:** Разделить строку по запятым, но там, где `|` (вроде экранирования), запятую нужно игнорировать.
Т.е. должно вернуть это:

```
["Казнить|, нельзя", " помиловать."]
```

Возможно просмотр назад дал бы пользу, но в `JS`, где мне это нужно сделать, такой фичи нет.
Максимум что добился - это деление по запятой (`/([^,]+)/g`, это было легко), без учёта `|` (а тут забуксовал) и головная боль.
Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

**UPD:**

По большому счёту не важно что будет номинально считаться экранированием запятой - обратный слэш, пайп или квадратик из ASCII-арта, но некто в ответах упёрся бараном в новые ворота на свойства экранирования `\`, поэтому теперь экранирует пайп.

Comment: А я упрусь и все-таки скажу - регулярки выполняют свою работу в узко заданном диапазоне. За пределами этого диапазона лучше их не трогать. Нет ничего страшного в том, чтобы написать свой собственный парсер о трех методах.

Comment: @Etki, Ни за что не поверю что регулярки не в силах справится с такой простой проблемой. Но зная их... не очень хорошо, решил что кто-то более знающий конкретно скажет: " - Да, это можно сделать так: ..." или " - Нет, этого в реализации JS нельзя сделать!". В три четыреста шага я и сам могу сделать.

Comment: Можно всё. Можно даже [распарсить HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/276994). Но [зачем](http://s003.radikal.ru/i201/1208/c1/d0e7323f980a.jpg)?

Comment: @VladD, Условия такие. Интерфейс, которому скармливаю строку, парсит по регулярке.
А ответ - Зачем? - ради лулзов? :) Не любим лёгких путей? Блажь такая?
Какая разница - вопрос такой и либо помоги, либо нет, тактично намекая что это не кошерно.

Comment: @TheDoctor: Смотрите. Во-первых, такая задача регулярками решается, она достаточно проста. Во-вторых, проста она для специалиста (а у нас тут из виртуозов был вроде только @ReinRaus). В-третьих, я бы не мучился и написал простенький парсер. Или разделил по запятой и потом склеил, если последний символ `|`. Или ещё как-нибудь. Но это потому, что я не спец по регуляркам, _мне_ так легче. [YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary).

Comment: @VladD, Решается - хочу узнать как.
Я, возможно, тоже по другому сделал бы, правда простенький парсер писать для этого...

Answer (score 1):

Давайте отталкиваться от того, что javascript поддерживает негативный просмотр вперед.
Тогда последовательность действий такова:

- Развернуть исходную строку
- Разбить полученную строку с помощью следующего регулярного выражения:
  `/,(?![|])/`
- Развернуть каждый элемент полученного массива совпадений и сам массив совпадений, чтобы получить искомый результат

Вот код:

```
// (!!!) Будьте осторожны, используя эту функцию *
var naiveReverse = function(string) {
    return string.split('').reverse().join('');
}

var string = "Казнить|, нельзя, помиловать.";

var reversed_array = naiveReverse(string).split(/,(?![|])/);

var result_array = reversed_array.map(function(item) {
    return naiveReverse(item);
}).reverse();
```

Результат:

```
["Казнить|, нельзя", " помиловать."]
```

Составлено на основе ответов к этим вопросам на StackOverflow:

- [Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11347100/2486051)
- * [How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776621/2486051)

Comment: Однозначно плюс :)   
Правда на костыль больше похоже...

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам такое уродство:

```
"Казнить|, нельзя, по,мил|,овать.".replace(/([^\|])\,/g, '$1###').replace(/\|\,/g,',').split('###')
```

Comment: Мдя... А неплохо :)
Проблема только в зависимости от наличия в строке "###". Если это будет, то всё поломается. Вряд ли будет, конечно, но ВДРУГ?

Comment: замени "###" на какой-нибудь хэш, например, дико коряво, но почти неубиваемо)

Comment: Есть такое :)
Но придумывать и вставлять левую строчку и дважды разгонять ядро регулярных выражений... Даже не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Увидел что Вы отказались от регулярного выражения и решил предложить вариант, который, наверное, в тысячу раз быстрее будет -

```js
var text = "Казнить|, нельзя, помиловать.";

function cut(text, search, ignore){
 var startIndex = 0,
  endIndex = 0,
  result = [];

 while((endIndex = text.indexOf(search, endIndex)) > -1){
  if(text.substring(endIndex, endIndex - 1) != ignore){
   result.push(text.substring(startIndex, endIndex));

   startIndex = endIndex;
  }

  endIndex++;
 }

 result.push(text.substring(startIndex, text.length));

 return result;
}

console.log(cut(text, ',', '|')); // [ 'Казнить|, нельзя', ', помиловать.' ]
```

```js
var text = "Казнить|, нельзя, помиловать.";

function cut(text, search, ignore){
 var startIndex = 0,
  endIndex = 0,
  isNotComplete = true,
  isPush = false,
  result = [];

 while(isNotComplete){
  isNotComplete = (endIndex = text.indexOf(search, endIndex)) > -1;

  if(isNotComplete && text.substring(endIndex, endIndex - 1) != ignore){
   isPush = true;
  }else if(!isNotComplete){
   isPush = true;
   endIndex = text.length;
  }

  if(isPush){
   result.push(text.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
   startIndex = endIndex;
   
   isPush = false;
  }

  endIndex++;
 }

 return result;
}

console.log(cut(text, ',', '|')); // [ 'Казнить|, нельзя', ', помиловать.' ]
```